# How can I construct my SQL query to select the two latest/most recent groups of records for each key field in a table in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

Given a data set for example as follows:

PERSON - the person allocating funds (key field)
EFFECTIVE DATE - the effective date of the percentage distribution
RECIPIENT - the person receiving a certain percentage of the funds
PERCENTAGE - the percentage that the person receives

(so for any given effective date, a person allocates a total of 100% to any given combination of recipients)

```
PERSON     EFFECTIVE DATE  RECIPIENT     PERCENTAGE 
---------- --------------- ------------- ----------- 
MONICA     2015-10-01      BARNEY        100%         +
MONICA     2015-09-01      BARNEY        50%          +
MONICA     2015-09-01      MARSHALL      20%          + 
MONICA     2015-09-01      LILY          30%          +
MONICA     2015-08-01      ROBIN         50%
MONICA     2015-08-01      TED           50%
CHANDLER   2015-10-01      ROBIN         50%          +
CHANDLER   2015-10-01      LILY          50%          +
CHANDLER   2015-07-10      BARNEY        50%          +
CHANDLER   2015-07-10      MARSHALL      50%          +
CHANDLER   2015-06-01      ROBIN         50%
CHANDLER   2015-06-01      LILY          50%
CHANDLER   2015-04-10      BARNEY        50%
CHANDLER   2015-04-10      MARSHALL      50%
ROSS       2015-10-01      MARSHALL      100%         +
ROSS       2015-09-15      BARNEY        100%         +
PHOEBE     2015-10-01      MARSHALL      20%          +
PHOEBE     2015-10-01      BARNEY        20%          +
PHOEBE     2015-10-01      LILY          20%          +
PHOEBE     2015-10-01      ROBIN         20%          +
PHOEBE     2015-10-01      TED           20%          +
PHOEBE     2015-09-01      MARSHALL      100%         +
PHOEBE     2015-08-01      BARNEY        100%
PHOEBE     2015-07-01      LILY          100%
PHOEBE     2015-06-01      ROBIN         100%
PHOEBE     2015-05-01      TED           100%
```

How can I construct a single SQL query that would return only the two latest sets of allocations per person at once (all of the records marked with a "+" above)? This is so that I could process the data into a display that says, for example, that:

"Monica changed allocation FROM 50% for Barney, 20% for Marshall, and 30% for Lily TO 100% for Barney."

"Chandler changed allocation FROM 50% for Barney, 50% for Marshall TO 50% for Robin, 50% for Lily."

"Ross changed allocation FROM 100% for Barney TO 100% for Marshall."

"Phoebe changed allocation FROM 100% for Marshall TO 20% for Marshall, 20% for Lily, 20% for Barney, 20% for Robin, 20% for Ted."

Comment: Side note: Do you have to distribute all, 100% of, the funds?  What happens to any remaining funds, after calculating from the percentage (because presumably you can't distribute fractions of cents...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method using `where`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.effective_date in (select t2.effective_date
                           from t t2
                           where t2.person = t.person
                           group by t2.effective_date
                           order by t2.effective_date desc
                           fetch first 2 rows only
                          );
```

You can also do this with `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by person order by effective_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: Wouldn't 'fetch first 2 rows only' return only 2 rows for the entire table - and not 2 rows per person?

Comment: @heisenbergman - If it was outside the subquery, then yes.  Since it's inside, it grants two rows for each time the subquery is invoked, which is for every row in the outer table.

Answer (score 0):

Can try like this.

```
select * 
from table as W 
where w.effective_date >= (
    //get 2nd max effective date 
    select max(a.effective_date) from table as a 
    where a.person = w.person
    and a.effective_date Not = (
        //get max of effective_date per person
        select max(x.effective_date) from table as x    
        where x.person = a.person)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

row_number is another option

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person order by effective_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```